# Spring Data JPA findAll throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have following autowired repository

```
@Repository
public interface ProsessiAjossaRepository extends JpaRepository<ProsessiAjossa, Long> {

    ProsessiAjossa findByProsessi(final Prosessi prosessi);
}
```

automatically generated `findById()` method works fine, but `findAll()` throws null pointer exception for some reason. What may be wrong?

Comment: corrupt data in DB?

Comment: share the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of the null pointer exception when using the findAll() method is that there is no data available in the database that matches the criteria specified. To troubleshoot this issue, try adding a few entries into the database and then running the findAll() method again. Additionally, you can also check the database for correct data type and field configurations, as these can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: if there is no data found when you call findAll(), then there will be no NPE, repository returns empty list in this case